# Using Entypo @font-face not working in IE8 or later?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

I just started using Entypo font-face to make my social icons, but in IE8 or later, it displays the font as an empty box. I don't know if there is something wrong with my code or their font.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'entypo-social';
src: url('entypo-social.eot');
src: url('entypo-social.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('entypo-social.woff') format('woff'),
     url('entypo-social.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('entypo-social.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); }


.social_font a{
font: 47px/20px 'entypo-social', Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entypo does not work in IE8. i just visited their website in IE8 and their demos are completely broken.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i've been using for font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFive';
    src: url('ChunkFive.eot');
    src: url('ChunkFive.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('ChunkFive.woff') format('woff'),
    url('ChunkFive.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('ChunkFive.svg#font') format('svg'); ;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

you could take a llok at this.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

By the way: font-face Do works in IE8.

Comment: I have tried that, and I think I have narrowed it down to not being an IE8 problem. But rather it being something wrong with the font I got from http://www.entypo.com/

Comment: Hi. Take a llok at this tutorial. [link](http://designfromwithin.com/blog-webdesign-development/2012/04/16/tutorial-cta-button-without-images-using-css3-and-entypo).They are using your font. I've test it my self in IE8.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial, but I have tested that myself, and you are right it works in IE8. But I am working with the social icons. The regular font works in all browsers including IE9 - IE7. I don't know if there is something wrong with the .eot file in the social folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use http://fontello.com/ - choose the entypo icons you need and download their package.
That worked in IE7+ for me.

Answer (score 0):

Double check you’ve not got IE’s **Compatibility View** selected. Just wasted over an hour without checking and it works fine when de-selected.

Also if you’re using html5shiv, try placing it after your css file containing the fonts.